# tengo un problema conceptual sobre este error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast

Tags: java

Buenas tardes, en un código que ando elaborando de manera empírica me encuentro con un fallo conceptual por parte mía y no sé como poderlo solucionar, el error es el siguiente:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to prodemios.proceso at prodemios.PrincipalES.main(PrincipalES.java:32

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
package prodemios;

import java.util.*;

public class PrincipalES {
    static String contraseña;
    static String usuario;
    static int validacion;
    static int puntosg;
    static int puntosf;
    static boolean encendido=true;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Si es usuario oprima 1, si es servidor oprima 2");
        validacion=leer.nextInt();

        switch(validacion){
        case 1:
            usuario();
            break;
        case 2:
            validar();
            break;
        }

        proceso user;
        serializador s = new serializador();
        user=(proceso)s.cargarObjeto("prodemios.dat");
        System.out.println(user.getNombre());
        System.out.println(user.getPuntos());
        //guardaD.
    }

    public static void validar(){
        Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
        BaseDatos BD=new BaseDatos();
        System.out.println("ingresa la contraseña");
        contraseña=leer.nextLine();
        if(contraseña.equals("prodemios")){
            BD.servidor();    
        }
        else{System.out.println("error en la contraseña");}
    }

    public static void usuario(){
        Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
        usuario usu= new usuario();
        System.out.println("bienvenido al prode, oprime A si eres usuario nuevo\nO B si eres usuario antiguo");
        usuario=leer.nextLine();

        if(usuario.equals("a")){    
          usu.usuarionuevo();
        }

        if(usuario.equals("b")){
           usu.usuarioantiguo(); 
        }

        proceso user;
        serializador s = new serializador();
        user=(proceso)s.cargarObjeto("prodemios.dat");
        System.out.println(user.getNombre());
        System.out.println(user.getPuntos());
    }
}
```

---

```
package prodemios;

import java.util.*;

public class BaseDatos {
    private int usuariosPuntos;
    private String usuariosNombre="";
    private int i;
    private int cantidad;
    private int cont;

    public void servidor() {
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("ingresa cantidad de usuarios");
        cantidad=leer.nextInt();

        proceso datos[]=new proceso[cantidad];

        for(i=0;i<=datos.length-1;i++){
            cont=cont+1;
            System.out.println("ingresa el nombre del usuario numero "+cont);
            usuariosNombre=leer.next();

            datos[i]=new proceso(usuariosNombre, usuariosPuntos);
        }

        cont=0;
        for(i=0;i<=datos.length-1;i++){
            cont=cont+1;
            System.out.println("ingresa los puntos del usuario numero "+cont);
            usuariosPuntos=leer.nextInt();

            datos[i]=new proceso(usuariosNombre, usuariosPuntos);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
package prodemios;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class usuario {
    private String nombre;
    private int puntosgeneral;
    private int puntosfecha;

    public void usuarionuevo(){
        Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("ingresa tu nombre");
        nombre=leer.next();

        System.out.println("ingresa tus puntos realizados");
        puntosgeneral=leer.nextInt();
        proceso pr = new proceso(nombre,puntosgeneral);
    }

    public void usuarioantiguo(){
        Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("ingresa tus puntos realizados en la fecha");
        puntosfecha=leer.nextInt();
        proceso pr = new proceso(null,puntosfecha);
    }

    public int getPuntosgeneral() {
        return puntosgeneral;
    }

    public void setPuntosgeneral(int puntosgeneral) {
        this.puntosgeneral = puntosgeneral;
    }

    public int getPuntosfecha() {
        return puntosfecha;
    }

    public void setPuntosfecha(int puntosfecha) {
        this.puntosfecha = puntosfecha;
    }
}
```

---

```
package prodemios;

public class proceso {
    private String nombre;
    private int puntos;

    public proceso(){       
        nombre="";
        puntos=0;
    }

    public proceso(String nom,int punt){
        nombre=nom;
        puntos=punt;
        serializador guardaD = new serializador();
        guardaD.guardaObjeto(getNombre(),getPuntos());  
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getPuntos() {
        return puntos;
    }

    public void setPuntos(int puntos) {
        this.puntos = puntos;
    }

    //usu.getPuntosgeneral();
    //usu.getPuntosfecha()
}
```

---

```
package prodemios;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class serializador {
    private ObjectInputStream cargarDato;
    private ObjectOutputStream guardarDato;

    public void guardaObjeto(Object nombre, Object puntos ){
        try {
            guardarDato= new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("prodemios.dat"));
            guardarDato.writeObject(nombre);
            guardarDato.writeObject(puntos);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Object cargarObjeto(String nombreArchivo){
        Object retorno = null;
        try {
            cargarDato= new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(nombreArchivo));
            retorno=cargarDato.readObject();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retorno;
    }
}
```

La clase proceso es la que recibe los datos de las clases BaseDato o usuario y construye los objetos que van directo al serializador, les agradecería mucho la ayuda, feliz tarde.

Comment: cabe aclarar que se cual es el error, lo que no sé es como corregirlo, muchas gracias!

Comment: Te sugiero que formatees el código pegado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user=(proceso)s.cargarObjeto("prodemios.dat");

Es el error por lo que ese método devuelve un String y lo intentas convertir en "proceso". Primero que todo según lo que tengo entendido esa no es la forma adecuada de guardar objetos. Para guardar un objeto lo primero que tiene implementar la clase del objeto que vayas a guardar, es la clase Serializable. Te recomiendo este post http://www.sc.ehu.es/sbweb/fisica/cursoJava/fundamentos/archivos/objetos.htm

Comment: muchas gracias por el post, en verdad me está siendo útil en este instante, :D

Comment: De nada bro, para eso estamos.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes está en la clase serializador (**Serializador**), y en concreto en el método "cargarObjeto", este método te está devolviendo un objeto que no puede hacer casting a proceso (**Proceso**).

Al hacer `MyClass mobj = (MyClass)obj` te estás encontrando con que className es diferente y no te puede hacer el casting.

> Solución: Por Interfaz, la más fácil te creas una interfaz con el método que vas a ejecutar por
>   ejemplo:

```
public interface InterfaceDTO{
    String getNombre();
}

public class Proceso implements InterfaceDTO{
 ..
 public String getNombre(){..}
}
```

Y luego haces el casting:

```
MyInterface mobj = (myInterface)obj;
mobj.doStuff();
```

> Solución: Por Reflección, algo más compleja conceptualmente.

```
MyClass mobj = MyClass.class.cast(obj);
```

Nota: Por definición y convenio los nombres de las clases van en mayúsculas y siguiendo las reglas de notación Cammell "ClasePersonalizadaEjemplo".

Comment: muchas gracias!!!!! :D

Comment: Para eso estamos, espero que te sea útil.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema parece ser que el dato que cargas es un String (el contenido del fichero prodemios.dat es interpretado como una cadena de caracteres), pero estás intentando interpretarlo como tipo "proceso". SEguro que lo has deserializado previamente correctamente en tal fichero?

Comment: Mirate la clase utilidad "Files" o la API de JSON-B, igual es mucho más fácil y estándar.hacer lo que te propones. La verdad es que el código es un poco rebuscado.

Comment: claro es rebuscado por que ando aprendiendo empiricamente, ese es el lio jajaja

Comment: 0
votar en contra
accept
realmente en ese tema estoy muy novato, y pretendia que me guardara en el fichero dos tipos de datos distintos por que necesito que me devuelva ambos para poder compararlo con un usuario nuevo que entre y se le envíe su posición en el array o se crea otra casilla mas, pero eso todavía no lo he realizado, lo que te entiendo entonces es que para lo que necesito debo usar dos ficheros, ¿es así?

Comment: No lo decía peyorativamente. Por eso te propongo que uses JSON o que si quieres leer y escribir datos en un fichero mires la API Files.

Comment: El problema de la estrtegia que estás usando es que tienes que ir leyendo los tipos y demás. Es más fácil. Crea el objeto que represente el contenido, Proceso.java o lo que sea, mete ahí su estructura, y luego serializalo  y deserializalo por completo. És más fácil, más documnentado y más estándar en JSON, sobretodo si luego has de mover esa info o integrarla  https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!! :D